# ServerConnection class not working due to depedency dlls

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

The [ServerConnection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.aspx) class gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error while instantiating. 
The class is perfectly working while running the application in a machine with visual studio.

But in a machine with just the framework(3.5) installed, it is not working.

Please help me fix the problem.

Note:  I have added the following 4 dlls in bin folder of the app.

1. Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended
2. Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
3. Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
4. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc

Comment: show the code that is giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the managment dlls you can install SharedManagementObjects from [this linq](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409) in production machine